# Highlighting search string in returned results

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

The `v-model` is `search` and it's linked with input field where user types in their search string.

Then, the computed method filters entries and returns those that contain search string.

The original, without search string highlighting, looks like this:

```js
computed: {
      filteredEntries() {
        if (this.search !== null && this.search !== '' && this.search.length > 0) {
          return this.json.filter(entry => {
            return JSON.stringify(entry).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
          })
        }
        else {
          return null
        }
      },
(...)
```

And what I tried to do ending up with an error looks like:

```js
computed: {
      filteredEntries() {
        if (this.search !== null && this.search !== '' && this.search.length > 0) {
          return this.json.filter(entry => {
            return JSON.stringify(entry.replace(
                                 this.search, 
                                 `<span style="background: #f0adf0;">${this.search}</span>`)
             ).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
          })
        }
        else {
          return null
        }
      },
(...)
```

The error thrown by Vue is `TypeError: entry.replace is not a function`.

`json` variable looks like (all values are searchable):

```js
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "owner": "Debbie",
        "items": "GTX-200, IOI-209, UTF-120"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "owner": "Greg",
        "items": "FVV-300, UPI-229, UDO-175"
    },
    (...)
]
```

Processed data is displayed withing constructs like:

```html
<v-card v-for="data in filteredEntries" :key="data.id">
  <v-card-title>{{ data.items }}</v-card-title>
</v-card>
```

Is it even possible to highlight the search string in here, or should it be done elsewhere?

Comment: which error and what are you using to render the highlighted content?

Comment: It's `TypeError: entry.replace is not a function` (I just put that into the post).

Comment: how does `json` look?

Comment: `json` added to the post. The proposal with conversion to string doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: How do you show that highlighted content?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the json array to string then replace the search value by that highlighted one :

```
computed: {
      filteredEntries() {
     return this.json.map(entry=>JSON.stringify(entry)).join('##').replace(this.search, `<span style='background: #f0adf0;'>${this.search}</span>`).split("##").map(entry=>JSON.parse(entry))
     }

}
```

```js
json = [{
    "id": 10,
    "owner": "Debbie",
    "items": "GTX-200, IOI-209, UTF-120"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "owner": "Greg",
    "items": "FVV-300, UPI-229, UDO-175"
  },
]

let search = "UPI"

let highlighted = json.map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry)).join('##').replace(search, `<span style='background: #f0adf0;'>${search}</span>`).split("##").map(entry => JSON.parse(entry))

console.log(highlighted)
```